# WoWLAN Wake on Wireless LAN with AR9462 - command not supported at 'iw enable'

Tags: wifi, wake-on-lan

I  try to enable Wake On Wireless LAN (WOW, WoWLAN) on my LinuxMint system with wifi AR9462 controller. I already tried several kernel versions (e.g. 3.19, ...). Currently, I run Ubuntu version 4.4.0-47.

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxx 4.4.0-47-generic #68~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
```

It's said, that network driver ath9k supports WOW, especially with AR9462.

```
$ lshw -C network
*-network
    description: Wireless interface
    product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    [...]
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-47-generic firmware=N/A ip=x.x.x.x latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

I use Ubuntu pre-compiled kernel. According to `/boot/config-4.4.0-47-generic`, WOW support in `ath9k` driver should be activated.

```
$  cat config-4.4.0-47-generic | grep WOW
CONFIG_ATH9K_WOW=y
```

However, as soon as I want to activate WOW with `iw` command, I get this output:

```
$  sudo iw phy phy0 wowlan show
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
$ sudo iw phy phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

Unfortunately, also `iw phy0 info` doesn't show anything about WOW support:

```
$ iw phy0 info
Wiphy phy0
    Band 1:
            Capabilities: 0x11ef
                    RX LDPC
                    HT20/HT40
                    SM Power Save disabled
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    RX HT40 SGI
                    TX STBC
                    RX STBC 1-stream
                    Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                    DSSS/CCK HT40
            Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
            Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
            HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
            Frequencies:
                    * 2412 MHz [1] (16.0 dBm)
                    [...]
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
    Band 2:
            Capabilities: 0x11ef
                    RX LDPC
                    HT20/HT40
                    SM Power Save disabled
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    RX HT40 SGI
                    TX STBC
                    RX STBC 1-stream
                    Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                    DSSS/CCK HT40
            Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
            Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
            HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
            Frequencies:
                    * 5180 MHz [36] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                    [...]
                    * 36.0 Mbps
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
            * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
            * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
            * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
            * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
            [...]
            * 00-0f-ac:12
    Available Antennas: TX 0x3 RX 0x3
    Configured Antennas: TX 0x3 RX 0x3
    Supported interface modes:
             * IBSS
             * managed
             * AP
             * AP/VLAN
             * WDS
             * monitor
             * mesh point
             * P2P-client
             * P2P-GO
             * Unknown mode (11)
    software interface modes (can always be added):
             * AP/VLAN
             * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
             * #{ managed } <= 2048, #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
               total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
             * #{ WDS } <= 2048,
               total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
    Supported commands:
             * new_interface
             * set_interface
             * new_key
             * new_beacon
             * new_station
             * new_mpath
             * set_mesh_params
             * set_bss
             * authenticate
             * associate
             * deauthenticate
             * disassociate
             * join_ibss
             * join_mesh
             * remain_on_channel
             * set_tx_bitrate_mask
             * action
             * frame_wait_cancel
             * set_wiphy_netns
             * set_channel
             * set_wds_peer
             * Unknown command (82)
             * Unknown command (81)
             * Unknown command (84)
             * Unknown command (87)
             * Unknown command (85)
             * Unknown command (89)
             * Unknown command (92)
             * connect
             * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
             * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             [...]
             * Unknown mode (10): 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
             * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             [...]
             * Unknown mode (10): 0x40 0xd0
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    HT Capability overrides:
             * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
             * maximum A-MSDU length
             * supported channel width
             * short GI for 40 MHz
             * max A-MPDU length exponent
             * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
```

How can I convince my system to activate Wake on wireless LAN on my WiFi card?

Comment: @GAD3R: Wake up on pci/e cards is enabled in BIOS. I was able to activate WOW on a Intel AC7260 wifi controller on the same system/installation. But that card has other drawbacks, so I wanna use the AR9462.