# Trying to enable WoWLAN with rtl8192cu - is it supported?

Tags: kernel, wifi, networkmanager, wlan

I'm using Ubuntu and following the [NetworkManager documentation](https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/reference/snap-configuration/wowlan) to enable WoWLAN. I'm worried that my wireless card does not support it. I installed NM through snap and followed the instructions (it came pre-installed without snap, which is confusing to me but I assume isn't a problem because the instructions for installing with snap did not mention it). I have enabled "Wake on PCIE" in the BIOS, and ran

```
snap set network-manager wifi.wake-on-wlan=any
```

However, when checking whether it's enabled:

```
$  sudo iw phy phy0 wowlan show
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

Does this mean that my wireless card just has no hope of supporting it? I don't know where to check, and [the kernel docs](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/wowlan) do not mention which drivers are supported. But I know that not all wifi cards support WoWLAN.

I don't know what model my wireless card is, but it's a USB card and `sudo lshw -C network` gives `driver=rtl8192cu`. I can get the rest of the output if it's helpful, but I'm posting from another machine so will need to use a pastebin.

I found [this unanswered question for AR9462](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323192/wowlan-wake-on-wireless-lan-with-ar9462-command-not-supported-at-iw-enable), which shows similar results but is for a different driver.

Comment: In the Debian [firmware-realtek](https://packages.debian.org/de/buster/firmware-realtek) package there exist some realtek firmwares supporting WoWLAN, but RTL8192CU is not among them. It's probably not supported.

Comment: @Freddy To make sure I'm understanding this correctly, does that same page suggest that RTL8192EU and RTL8723BS do support WoWLAN, for example? I'm probably going to buy a new wifi card if this one doesn't support it, so it's helpful to be able to tell which ones do.

Comment: I can't test or confirm it, but that's how I interpret it. Maybe there are other chipsets and drivers that support it out-of-the-box, but I don't know...

Comment: Thanks, no problem. I'll ask a separate question if I'm unsure. I assume any reasonably modern card from a manufacturer who is usually well supported on Linux will support it.